# Last value to found and replace in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

what if i have this particural case:
my array principal : `[1,2,3,4,1,2,5,1,2,3,4,5]` 
And my other array macro to which I can assign a size in this case (3): `['', '', '']`

So now I need to insert values in order from principal to macro:

Example:

For the first time the array macro is empty but i have to fill this array in this order.
`macro : [1, 2 ,3]` and `principal: [4,1,2,5,1,2,3,4,5]` but now when the array macro is full i need to replace a value from macro but this value need to be the last to appear in the principal array.

Let me try to explain: i have 3 values in macro 1 , 2 and 3.
so

if i got `value = 1` i will check in the principal array -> `[ 4, **1**` i found 1 but hes not the last.

now with `value = 2 -> [4, 1 ,**2**` i found 2 but hes not the last 
and with `value = 3 -> [4, 1, 2 , 5 ,1 ,2 , **3**` and now we got the last value

In this case the last value will be... **3** and i have to replace 3 with the first value of principal and my new macro array will be: `[1,2,4]`

A conditional for this problem: if i found an equal value between macro and principal i need to avoid him and continue with the next value

```
macro -> 1,2,4     principal [1,2,5,1,2,3,4,5]`
```

i need to avoid 1,2 from principal and continue with from 5.

```
macro -> 1,2,4     principal [5,1,2,3,4,5]`
```

the last will be 4 so i will replace the 4 in macro : `[1,2,5]`

A piece of code that i was trying to do...

```
function resolution()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < marcos.length; i++)
    {
        if(macro[i] == principal[i])
        {
            var exists = principal.indexOf(principal[i]);
        }

        if(array.length > 0)
        {
           //for i < array.length
            macro.splice(array[i] , 1 , cadena[i])
        }
        else
        {
            macro.splice(i, 1, cadena[i]);
        }
    }

    console.log(macro)
    principal.splice(0, macro.length);
}
```

I will appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: input is `macro : [1, 2 ,3] and principal: [4,1,2,5,1,2,3,4,5]`? and your output would be?

Comment: the final output -> [3,4,5]

Comment: could you please edit your question and add more examples... it is not clear :(

Comment: Is this your algorithm:
(1). if macro.size < 3 => fill at end of `macro` from start of `principal`
(2). if start of `principal` exists in macro => remove it till a different one is at the start
(3). for all in `macro`:
   (a). remove the element if its not in `principal` and restart loop to step 1.
   (b). if more than one occurance of element in `principal` skip to next
   (c). if only one occurance of element => replace it by first element of `principal` and restart loop to step 1
   (d). if more than one occurance of element in `principal` and the element is the last do as step 3.c.